# How to cache .mp4 files in Safari with workbox-webpack-plugin?

Tags: safari, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm having exactly the same issue reported at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1663 which describes an issue that occurs exclusively in Safari where mp4 videos are not rendered after being cached by the service worker.

I'm using `workbox-webpack-plugin`, so the instructions provided in the comment https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1663#issuecomment-448755945 will not work in my case. I'm not being able to require `workbox-range-requests` plugin in my webpack config file and pass it to the runtime caching options because I believe this package is intended for browser usage only. My workbox config is precaching .mp4 assets and uses a network first strategy for runtime caching.

How can I setup `workbox-range-requests` with `workbox-webpack-plugin`?

EDIT: Following [Jeff's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012365/1694191), I've adjusted my webpack config to the following:

```js
new WorkboxPlugin.InjectManifest({
   swSrc: serviceWorkerSrcPath,
   swDest: serviceWorkerBuildPath,
   importsDirectory: 'sw',
})
```

The build produces the following service worker:

```js
importScripts("/_build/sw/precache-manifest.8a0be820b796b153c97ba206d9753bdb.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.2/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
   /.*\.mp4/,
   new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'videos',
      plugins: [
         new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({ statuses: [200] }),
         new workbox.rangeRequests.Plugin(),
      ],
   }),
);
```

If forgot to mention previously, but I've also added `crossOrigin="anonymous"` attribute to the `video` elements.

EDIT:

Repro that demonstrates it does not work as expected on Safari: https://github.com/acostalima/workbox-range-requests-mp4-demo

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem. Still can't get it to work even with range requests plugin.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda sorry for the very late reply. I ended up implementing my own solution as a workaround at the time. I didn't have the chance  to follow at Workbox's but since almost two years have gone by now, this issue has probably already been solved at this point.

Answer (score 2):

There's specific guidance for this use case in the "[Serve cached audio and video](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av)" recipe in the Workbox documentation.

You can continue using the `workbox-webpack-plugin`, but I'd suggest using it in `InjectManifest` mode, which will give you control over the top-level service worker file. That will in turn make it possible to follow the recipe.

[This documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/webpack) has guidance on configuring `workbox-webpack-plugin` in `InjectManifest` mode.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I've edited my question with my updated webpack config. I was indeed using `GenerateSW` instead of `InjectManifest` plugin. However, the proposed recipe is still not working. Videos are rendered when I open the page with a clean cache, but on reload they are no longer rendered. The service worker is responding with a status of 200 instead of 206.

Comment: That would imply that `workbox-range-requests` isn't taking effect. It's probably going to be cleaner at this point to follow up in the Workbox issue tracker, if you don't mind providing more details (like a link to your live web app) there. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Safari and managed to resolve it by removing my video from the precahe list `self.__precacheManifest` and instead by adding it in the service worker's install handler:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {

        const urls = [/* videoUrl */];
        const cacheName = 'videos';
        event.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => cache.addAll(urls)));
});
```

Looking at the logs, it seemed that otherwise only the precache was used to respond to the request for the video resource and not the router.

Comment: Which URL did you use for the video url? I am having local videos served from my build/static folder, I'm not sure how to reference them, any advice?

Comment: I used precaching, so the ones generated by the precache manifest: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/webpack

Answer (score 0):

Although the docs say that adding mp4s to the precache cache and then configuring the range plugin to handle precache mp4s is supposed to work, in practice, it wasn't. Removing mp4s from the precache and configuring your own video cache with the range plugin did the trick for me. Don't forget to add the `crossorigin="anonymous"` tag to your videos!

Here's how I did it (webpack 5, workbox 6):

```
// src/service-worker.js
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import { cacheNames } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { RangeRequestsPlugin } from 'workbox-range-requests';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { CacheFirst } from 'workbox-strategies';

const allEntries = self.__WB_MANIFEST; // Injected by WorkboxWebpackPlugin at compile time
const videoEntries = allEntries.filter((entry) => entry.url.endsWith('.mp4'));
const restEntries = allEntries.filter((entry) => !entry.url.endsWith('.mp4'));

precacheAndRoute(restEntries);

const videoCacheName = `${cacheNames.prefix}-videos-${cacheNames.suffix}`;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const allVideosAddedToCache = caches.open(videoCacheName).then((videoCache) => {
    const videoUrls = videoEntries.map((entry) => entry.url);
    return videoCache.addAll(videoUrls);
  });
  event.waitUntil(allVideosAddedToCache);
});

registerRoute(
  (route) => route.url.pathname.endsWith('.mp4'),
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: videoCacheName,
    plugins: [new CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [200] }), new RangeRequestsPlugin()],
  })
);
```

```
// webpack.config.js
plugins: [
  new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
    swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
  }),
]
```

```
// index.tsx
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
  });
}
```